# is there a way to use different rate limit for each api key in express nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, rate-limiting

is there a way to use different rate limit for each api key in express nodejs?

for example api key "guest" has a rate limit of 500 requests per day and api key "key" has a rate limit of 1000 requests per day.

Comment: Are you asking about regulating incoming requests to different rate limits based on key?  Or are you  asking about regulating outgoing requests to some other host based on which key is being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simple solution is to use an npm package called [express-rate-limit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit), it's a popular one and express recommend to use it.

If the package doesn't work for you, it can be implemented using **redis**, **redis** is a memory database, so you can create a record with a sliding time. When a request come in you can update or create  the record, if the limit was reached you block the request, that logic can be implemented in a middleware.

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express');
const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');

const app = express();

// Define rate limit middleware for API1
const api1Limiter = rateLimit({
  max: 50,  // Maximum requests
  windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000,  // 1 hour window
  message: 'Too many requests from this IP for API1, please try again in an hour!',
});

// Define rate limit middleware for API2
const api2Limiter = rateLimit({
  max: 100,  // Maximum requests
  windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000,  // 1 hour window
  message: 'Too many requests from this IP for API2, please try again in an hour!',
});

// Apply rate limit middleware to specific routes
app.use('/api/api1', api1Limiter);
app.use('/api/api2', api2Limiter);

// Your API routes go here...

// Start the server
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
});
```